# south migration: "database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField" (mysql)

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm new to django and trying to have a Foreign key back to users for an assignee and reporter.
But when i'm trying to apply the change with South i get the error

```
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

My Model Code:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    prioritys = models.ForeignKey(Prioritys)
    ticket_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticket_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='assignee')
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='reporter')

    def escaped_text(self):
        return markdown.markdown(self.text)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Full StackTrace, please... + which ver. of django, south and mysql do U use?

Comment: @Adrián: I am having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 11):

If this happens when you run `manage.py migrate` (or `manage.py syncdb` in old versions), the reason maybe is that you have tried to add a foreign key to a model which uses AutoField as its primary key, and use 0 as the default value. **Edit the migration file and remove the argument `default=0` in AddField operations.** It works for me in Django 1.10.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't using South, but I recently upgraded from Django 1.4 to 1.6 (with MySQL as db backend for both), and was getting the same `ValueError` when trying to save some models.  I tracked it down to a field that was a recursive ForeignKey.  So I had:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    duplicate = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Somewhere along the line—unfortunately I'm not sure where—many of my objects had gotten the value of `0` for `duplicate_id`.

```
>>> Foo.objects.filter(duplicate_id=0).count()
2078
```

This didn't occur for any of my other `ForeignKey` fields, only the self-referential one.  So I set the values of that field back to `None`, and this fixed the error.

```
>>> Foo.objects.filter(duplicate_id=0).update(duplicate=None)
2078L
```

Because this particular error doesn't point you to a specific field that's causing problems, in general you can check if a ForeignKey field `fieldname` has any `0` values:

```
>>> Foo.objects.filter(fieldname_id=0).count()
```

If this gives a non-zero result, that field probably needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yep.  Exactly my problem as well.  Very odd and who knows how long that has been there.

Comment: indeed very hard to track down!

Comment: Wow, this fixed my issue too!

Answer (score 1):

A long-long time ago there was a problem with Autofield.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17653

an interesting quotes:

A:

> It seems you are trying to save 0 to a ForeignKey which points to an
>   AutoField. But, this is illegal, as the AutoField will not accept that
>   value and so the ForeignKey can not hold that value either.

B:

> So this fix creates another problem when you need to be able to accept
>   a value of 0 (or if you are working on a DB that already has a value
>   of 0!) in an autofield. In my case, I need to accept an ID of zero so
>   that my foreign key can point to zero so that a unique constraint can
>   work properly.

It looks like you have `0` in `"user"."user_id"`.
But again... Full StackTrace, please...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after upgrading to django 1.7.1 
it was caused when saving a model that had a foreign key to another model that for some reason had an id starting auto increment with 0, i guess this was allowed in previous django versions, but not now.