# Django manage.py test: “database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField” (mysql)

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-migrations, django-tests

I am trying to run the Django tests file using:

`python3.6 manage.py test`

I use: **MySQL 5.5.62**, **Python 3.6**, **Django 2.0.0**

It starts installing a test DB and fails with the error:

```
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

I searched for this error but all the topics I found were related to migrations, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328905/south-migration-database-backend-does-not-accept-0-as-a-value-for-autofield). I have no problem with migrations, they run smoothly.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 59, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 548, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 176, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 68, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 141, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 509, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 613, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 224, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 936, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 940, in get_db_prep_value
    value = connection.ops.validate_autopk_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 163, in validate_autopk_value
    raise ValueError('The database backend does not accept 0 as a '
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

How can I fix this error and run the tests?

Comment: Well based on the traceback, it indeed happens during migrations: the migrations of the test database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, this is indeed true, but what can I do about test migrations? They have no migration files in the migrations folder.

Comment: Take a look a this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46402659/6808714

Comment: @MahrezBenHamad Thanks, I had already seen it prior posting, but took me a while to realize those were the migrations problems caused by switching to MTPP with a workaround of setting lft, level, etc... to 0 and then removing those fields. I ended up deleting the migrations as this is a test project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems it was indeed migrations as [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) suggested. I ended up deleting the migrations and that cleared the issue.

It might be worth pointing out the the mess was caused by switching from Django models to Django MTPP models and using `0` as a default value for the newly added MTPP fields to avoid another issue in that process.